# Чем отличаются датаграммы, пакеты и кадры?

Tags: сеть, http, маршрутизация, tcp-ip, пакет

Не могу понять, чем отличаются пакеты, датаграммы и кадры? И не одно и то же ли это? Понятно, что перед отправкой данные разбиваются на блоки по максимальному размеру mtu, верно? Но что это за блоки получаются: датаграммы, пакеты или кадры - не пойму.

Answer (score 0):

Вы прав - все 3 термины обозначают то же самое - *блок информации дополненный головкой соответствующего протокола*.

Только по условности они применяются различно для различных уровней [Сетевой модели OSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI):

- на *канальном* уровне: **кадры**
- нa *сетевом* уровне: **пакеты**
- на *транспортном* зровне: **сегменты** или **дейтаграммы**

И так говорят об `IP` *пакетах* или об `TCP` *дейтаграммах*.
(Но нет ничего плохого сказать "IP *кадр*"  или "TCP *пакет*" - это только непривычное.)

*Примечание:*

MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) применяется только для `IP` протокола.